# How to migrate a website from codeigniter to wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, codeigniter

I have a website made with codeigniter and I would like to transfer it to wordpress.
Keeping the same database and the same contents.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Your question is to vague and does not relate a specific issue. Typically these type of questions can not be answered directly. Please refer to StackOverflow's [Guideline on How-To-Ask-A-Good-Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is not possible in a simple way no matter of your codeigniter version.

**That's because:**

- CodeIgniter is "just" a framework where the database schema is totally free designed by the developer and not folling a strict pattern (just some basic naming conventions)
- The WordPress views (final site's html) is generated more from database content and less from coded html whereas codeigniter uses the common mvc-pattern where most of the html is actually coded in the view files
- These are **in no way** comparable type of systems:

  - **WordPress is a CMS**
  - **CodeIgniter is a MVC-Framework**

---

If I had to migrate a website from codeigniter to wordpress I would build the page-structure by hand. I then would look at the final generated website (from CodeIgniter) in the browser and copy that content by hand in the wordpress pages.